# Remove noises inside circles with morphological operations

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

In the following image which is edges of some coins detected by Canny, I want to remove the extra edges detected inside the coins.

Since widths of all the edges are the same, I think I can't use erosion. Is there a way to remove these lines just using morphological operations?

[image]

Comment: Get the contours and remove the small noise by length or just get the external contours.

Comment: @fmw42, is it possible to remove them using only the basic morphological operations such as dilation and erosion?

Comment: No, I do not think so, since all the circles are the same thickness as the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`remove_small_objects`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects) from the sklearn package. You would probably have to do some dilation/closing prior.

Another strategy is to do a dilation/closing followed by performing a [`regionprops`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html?highlight=regionprops#skimage.measure.regionprops) to find each region's perimeter and radius. If the perimeter is similar to the radius * 2pi (perimeter of a circle), than you keep that region in your image.

You have options!